# OpenVPN connection reachable but times out

Tags: vpn, openvpn, netgear

What I'm trying to do:

- Set up my own VPN server using a VPN-supported router (in this case, OpenVPN supported by Netgear Nighthawk X6 R8000)
- Be able to access both internal network and internet with this VPN server
- I've chosen Viscosity as my client based off of performance statistics (as opposed to Tunnelblick, free but not as reliable from multiple reviews)

Problem: OpenVPN connection reachable but times out

Logs below:

TCP:

```
Nov 22 15:13:00: Viscosity Mac 1.5.11 (1314)
Nov 22 15:13:00: Viscosity OpenVPN Engine Started
Nov 22 15:13:00: Running on Mac OS X 10.10.3
Nov 22 15:13:00: ---------
Nov 22 15:13:00: Checking reachability status of connection...
Nov 22 15:13:01: Connection is reachable. Starting connection attempt.
Nov 22 15:13:01: OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-apple-darwin [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Sep 23 2015
Nov 22 15:13:01: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.09
Nov 22 15:13:02: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Nov 22 15:13:02: Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]<PublicIP>:12974 [nonblock]
Nov 22 15:13:14: TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<PublicIP>:12974 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Operation timed out
Nov 22 15:13:24: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

UDP:

```
Nov 22 18:26:18: Viscosity Mac 1.5.11 (1314)
Nov 22 18:26:18: Viscosity OpenVPN Engine Started
Nov 22 18:26:18: Running on Mac OS X 10.10.3
Nov 22 18:26:18: ---------
Nov 22 18:26:18: Checking reachability status of connection...
Nov 22 18:26:19: Connection is reachable. Starting connection attempt.
Nov 22 18:26:19: OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-apple-darwin [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Sep 23 2015
Nov 22 18:26:19: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.09
Nov 22 18:26:20: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Nov 22 18:26:20: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Nov 22 18:26:20: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]<PublicIP>:12974
Nov 22 18:27:20: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Nov 22 18:27:20: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Nov 22 18:27:20: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Nov 22 18:27:29: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

config.conf:

```
#-- Config Auto Generated By Viscosity --#

#viscosity startonopen false
#viscosity dhcp true
#viscosity dnssupport true
#viscosity name client2
#viscosity ipv6 false
remote HOSTNAME 12974 udp
pull
tls-client
persist-key
ca ca.crt
nobind
persist-tun
cert cert.crt
comp-lzo adaptive
dev tap
key key.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
resolv-retry infinite
```

I did about 2 hrs of googling and still did not come up with a viable answer :(.

**The players:**

- Motorola SBG6580 Modem/Router with Wireless Bridging enabled (Motorola GUI > Wireless > 802.11 Bridging > Wireless Bridging "Enabled" selected)
- Brand new Netgear Nighthawk X6 R8000 Router with OpenVPN support
- Mac OS X 10.10.3
- No-IP address registered, ping-able
- Viscosity Mac 1.5.11 (1314) - Latest Stable Version

**Basic checks:**

- Enabled said router's OpenVPN support (ref: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/25389/~/how-do-i-use-the-vpn-service-on-my-r8000-router-with-my-mac-os-computer%3F)
- Settings: TCP/port 12974 (also tried UDP/port 12974)

**Neither my router nor my modem is blocking any ports that I can see:**

1) Motorola Modem/Router:

- Firewall set to "Low" protection with "No Ports Restricted", "Block Fragmented IP Packets" disabled, "Port Scan Detection" disabled, "IP Flood Detection" disabled
- "WAN Blocking" disabled, "Ipsec PassThrough" enabled, "PPTP PassThrough" enabled, "Remote Config Mgmt" disabled, "Multicast Enable" enabled, "UPnP Enable" enabled
- NAT ALG Status Enabled on:
  FTP, TFTP, Kerb88, Kerb1293, ICQ, ICQTalk, IRC666x, IRC7000, IRC8000, H225, RSVP, NetBios, MSN, PPTP, Net2Phone, RTSP, IKE, SIP

2) Netgear Router:

- Added Dynamic DNS Service entry from NoIP: Netgear GUI > Advanced > Advanced Setup > Dynamic DNS: hostname/HOSTNAME.ddns.net, username, pass
- Added a services blocking rule: VPN-OpenVPN / 12974 / all IP's / Never blocked
  (under Advanced > Security > Block Services)

3) Viscosity:

- Remote Server: HOSTNAME.ddns.net
- Port: 12974
- Protocol: TCP
- Device: tap
- Enable DHCP (checked)
- Authentication: Type: SSL/TLS Client
- everything else set to default options

Not sure where to go from there.

I've already restarted all my gear several times, no change;

toggled OpenVPN support on router, no change;

re-installed Viscosity, no change;

even tried freebie version Tunnelblick, also connectivity issues.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this would be much much appreciated, as I am still a newb to VPN in general.
Thank you!

Comment: So you are trying to connect to a openvpn server that someone else manages? The message: "WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled" seems to be your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to set up my own vpn server using my vpn-supported router (Netgear Nighthawk X6 R8000). Ex: First method listed here: http://www.howtogeek.com/221001/how-to-set-up-your-own-home-vpn-server/

Comment: Also, a note: Netgear's Nighthawk only supports OpenVPN on its native manufacturer firmware. I am considering DD-WRT, but as I have never done that level of customization on a router before, I don't really want to try that on the Nighthawk til I've experimented on a cheaper router first.  Hence, the OpenVPN natively-supported option on the Nighthawk.

Comment: I have never setup openvpn with that router before. But anytime I have setup openvpn I have always had to import a certificate from the server so that I could make it work. Did you do something similar with certificates like the tunnelblock document you link has in it?

Comment: Yes, they're just config files. They're mentioned in the steps I had followed in http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/25389/~/how-do-i-use-the-vpn-service-on-my-r8000-router-with-my-mac-os-computer%3F. I double checked that those params were correct and match my NoIP account.

Comment: have a look here: https://www.sparklabs.com/support/getting_started/ Specifically Step 4. Do you have certificates entered in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31994/discussion-between-eddie-dunn-and-jay).